# Using an external truststore and keystore for postgres

Tags: docker, ssl, keystore, postgresql-10, truststore

I am trying to enable SSL for Postgres 10.  Rather than specifying a ca file, though, I would like to use a truststore.jks and keystore.p12 that is given to me.  Postgres and our communicating services are each in their own docker container.  The services are able to share the truststore and keystore by having them in a shared volume mount and using the basic Java commands on startup:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TRUSTSTORE_NAME}
```

However, postgres doesn't work the same way (to my knowledge).  It has the following properties in the postgresql.conf:

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/server.crt'   
ssl_key_file = '/server.key'
ssl_ca_file = '/root.crt'
ssl_crl_file = '/ssl.crl'
```

This will work if I have access to those certs.  However, I don't want to point to specific certs, because they will already be in the truststore and I will not know their alias - I want to instead say "use this truststore that I am giving you".  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java KeyStore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) (*.jks) is a Java-specific format and PostgreSQL is not written in Java, so that alone disqualifies your truststore+keystore configuration.

As for [PKCS12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) (*.p12 file extension), while it's a platform-independent standard, I've only ever seen in used in relation to PostgreSQL with various clients (most notably JDBC-based) and never to supply certificates to the server.

Taking all that into account, OP, you'll unfortunately have to extract the certiticates and use them directly.

Comment: Not sure how 'extracting certificates' would help as you cannot specify multiple client cert to be trusted. Seems to me you are forced to generated a CA (could be self signed) which you then need to use to generate the certs for the clients that are supposed to connect to the postgres server. Then use that CA in the postgres server.

Comment: @Martin Neither the OP nor I have mentioned anything about multiple client certificates being used. My assumption is that keystore.p12 contains server certificate and key, while truststore.jks contains one or more CAs used to sign one or more client certificates. Those are the certificates (and key) that OP needs to extract. If the OP’s truststore actually contains specific client certificates, then he’s indeed screwed as Postgres does not allow specifying those - merely their CNs to be used in conjunction with CA(s).

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-CLIENT-CERTIFICATES

Comment: Thank you for the quick clarification!